# spark streaming on EMR and S3 source

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, emr

I am trying to print a stream using s3 as source using the zeppelin notebook in EMR.

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 45)
streams=ssc.textFileStream('s3://realtime-nyc-bike/')
streams.pprint()
```

However, nothing is getting printed. The Bucket name is correct. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From Spark streaming documentation:

Spark Streaming only sets up the computation it will perform when it is started, and no real processing has started yet. To start the processing after all the transformations have been setup, finally call

```
ssc.start()             // Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  // Wait for the computation to terminate
```